# Video call app with 60FPS support

Tags: video-conferencing

I am looking for a video call app which supports 60FPS. It's not necessary but would be nice if it comes with cross platform clients support.

There may not be a direct comparison, but with the advent and abundance of 60FPS videos, I am wondering if there's a video call app which supports 60FPS in real time. Internet bandwidth and latency is not a constraint.

Answer (score 0):

[multiparty-meeting](https://github.com/havfo/multiparty-meeting) - demo at https://letsmeet.no/ - supports advanced options, including forcing 60fps video redording and encoding.